# Python: SQL left join (аналог в SQL Alchemy)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Сделал такой SQL запрос:

```
    SELECT *
FROM kit.layout
  LEFT JOIN kit.layout_style ON kit.layout.id = kit.layout_style.layout_id
  LEFT JOIN kit.catalog_style_layout ON kit.catalog_style_layout.id = kit.layout_style.catalog_style_layout_id
  LEFT JOIN kit.catalog_style_template ON kit.catalog_style_template.id = kit.catalog_style_layout.catalog_style_template_id
  LEFT JOIN kit.catalog_style_tag ON kit.catalog_style_tag.id = kit.catalog_style_layout.catalog_style_tag_id
  LEFT JOIN kit.catalog_style_tag_value ON kit.catalog_style_tag_value.catalog_style_tag_id = kit.catalog_style_tag.id
WHERE kit.layout.id = 6624;
```

Как реализовать тоже самое, но только через SQL Alchemy?

Comment: https://habr.com/company/eastbanctech/blog/226521/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на чистом SQL (минуя ORM), то например вот так:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
# конфигурация подключения к БД пропущена

rows = db.engine.execute('тут sql').fetchall()
```

Comment: Благодарю, подскажите, а как реализовать через ORM. Мне бы сам механизм понять.

Comment: @mroldsir вам нужно продумать иерархию (схему) БД и по данным сущностям (таблицам) построить набор моделей (классов) унаследованных от классов моделей sqlalchemy, которые содержат описание полей таблиц. Более подробно можете почитать и посмотреть примеры вы можете на сайте [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)